# Aggregate values from a joined table with change tracking

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have a person table + some values from a join on organisations that a person is related to in my DB that I want to have in an index.

I'm currently doing this be using a view in the database however that means that I can no longer used the inbuilt change tracking.

The view looks something like this:

```sql
CREATE VIEW [vw_person_detail]
AS 
    select                                          
        p.id                                        
    ,   p.full_name                                 
    ,   p.first_name                                
    ,   p.middle_name                               
    ,   p.last_name                                 
    ,   e.recs number_of_links                  

    from person p                           
    left join (                                     
        select
            person
        ,   count(*) recs
        from linkedtable
        group by person
    ) e on e.person = p.id
```

So can I do this via a complex type in the Azure search so that I can then use the inbuilt CDC to provide deltas on my index?

Cheers..

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [FOR JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#2b---example-with-join-and-null) function to get your data in a structure (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-complex-data-types#example-of-a-complex-structure) that you can use [rebuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-reindex) your indexes

If you don't find this helpful, let me know. I'll do what I can to help.